# While loop doesn't exit when eof is detected

Tags: while-loop, pascal, eof

I'm having troubles with the eof sequence at the while loop. Basically I have to read a txt file (sequence) and each character has a different character that will be printed on an exit.txt file. But my while loop doesn't recognize the eof. Here's my code.

```
program LaboratorioPascal;
uses crt;
var 
    sec, sal: Textfile;
    v: char;
    por_especial, cont_palabra, cont_caracter, cont_especial: integer; 
    vocales2: set of char;
    pares: set of char;
    impares: set of char;
    consonantes: set of char;
    consonantes2: set of char;

    procedure numeros(var x: char);
    begin 
        case x of
            '0': Write(sal, '0');
            '1': Write(sal, '1');
            '2': Write(sal, '4');
            '3': begin 
                     Write(sal, '2'); 
                     Write(sal, '7');
                 end;
            '4': Write(sal, '8');
            '5': begin
                     Write(sal, '1'); 
                     Write(sal, '2'); 
                     Write(sal, '5');
                 end; 
            '6': begin
                     Write(sal, '1');
                     Write(sal, '2');
                 end; 
            '7': begin
                     Write(sal, '3'); 
                     Write(sal, '4'); 
                     Write(sal, '3');
                 end;
            '8': begin
                     Write(sal, '1'); 
                     Write(sal, '6');
                 end;
            '9': begin
                     Write(sal, '7');
                     Write(sal, '2'); 
                     Write(sal, '9');
                 end;
            else Exit;
        end;
    end;

    function vocales(var s: char): char;
    begin
        case s of 
            'e': vocales := 'u';
            'a': vocales := 'o';
            'i': vocales := 'a';
            'o': vocales := 'e';
            else vocales := 'i';
        end;
    end;

begin
    assign(sec, 'input.txt');   // Le asignamos un archivo del cual lea
    reset(sec);                 // arrancamos la secuencia
    read(sec, v);               // leemos la secuencia. avz(sec, v)
    assign(sal, 'salida.txt');
    rewrite(sal);
    vocales2 := ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    pares :=  ['0', '2', '4', '6', '8'];
    impares :=  ['1', '3', '5', '7', '9'];
    consonantes := ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j','k','l','m', 'n'];
    consonantes2 := ['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
    por_especial := 0;
    cont_palabra := 0;
    cont_caracter := 0;
    cont_especial := 0;
    writeln('El objetivo de este programa es cifrar un mensaje para favorecer a la inteligencia Rusa.');

    while not eof(sec) do 
    begin
        while v = ' ' do 
        begin
            write(sal, ' ');
            read(sec, v);
        end;

        cont_palabra := cont_palabra + 1;

        while v <> ' ' do
        begin
            if (v in consonantes) or (v in consonantes2) then 
            begin
                write(sal, '1');
            end
            else
            begin
                if v in vocales2 then
                begin
                    Write(sal, vocales(v));
                end
                else
                begin
                    if v in pares then;
                    begin
                        numeros(v);
                    end;

                    begin
                        if v in impares then
                        begin
                            numeros(v);
                        end
                        else
                        begin
                            cont_especial := cont_especial + 1;
                            Write(sal, '@');
                        end;
                    end;
                end;
            end;

            read(sec, v);
        end;
    end;

    write(cont_palabra, ' se crifraon con [Exito]');
    
    close(sec);
    close(sal);
end.
```

But the result I have in the exit file (salida.txt) is

```
1o1ao i1o 1u1 i1 1e1111ie 1iu 1u 1e1ae o i1o 11a11u1o@@@ 1a1@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

I've done my research about the eof topic, but I can't find anything about pascal. And if I try to put an

```
if eof then
    Exit;
end;
```

inside the while loop, and it just read one character from the input.txt file.

Comment: The pseudocode tag clearly doesn't apply here, because you're compiling and executing your code, so I've removed it. Also, have you stepped through the code in a debugger to see exactly what it's doing?

Comment: You have "if v in pares then;" which looks like a mistake. Notice the ; at the end.

Comment: Also the first read from sec is not protected by EOF checks So an empty file might do strange things

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are in the inner loop ("while v <> ' ' do") when you come to the end of your input file.
If the last character in the input file is a space, you jump out of the inner loop and out of the outer loop, because you reached eof.
But if it isn't, you stay in the inner loop, and keep reading beyond the eof, until you encounter a space or a problem.

You can change the inner loop's
"while v <> ' ' do"
to
"while (v <> ' ') and (not eof(sec)) do".

Or make it one loop and handle the space in an if statement.